# How to overwrite multiple rows from one row (iloc/loc difference)?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe and would like to assign multiple values from one row to multiple other rows.
I get it to work with .iloc but for some when I use conditions with .loc it only returns nan.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(A = [1,2,0,0],B=[0,0,0,10],C=[3,4,5,6]))
df.index = ['a','b','c','d']
```

When I use loc with conditions or with direct index names:

```
df.loc[df['A']>0, ['B','C']] = df.loc['d',['B','C']]
df.loc[['a','b'], ['B','C']] = df.loc['d',['B','C']]
```

it will return

```
     A       B       C
a   1.0     NaN     NaN
b   2.0     NaN     NaN
c   0.0     0.0     5.0
d   0.0     10.0    6.0
```

but when I use .iloc it actually works as expected

```
df.iloc[0:2,1:3] = df.iloc[3,1:3]
```

```
    A   B   C
a   1   10  6
b   2   10  6
c   0   0   5
d   0   10  6
```

is there a way to do this with .loc or do I need to rewrite my code to get the row numbers from my mask?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use labels, pandas perform index alignment, and in your case there is no common indices thus the NaNs, while location based indexing does not align.

You can assign a numpy array to prevent index alignment:

```
df.loc[['a','b'], ['B','C']] = df.loc['d',['B','C']].values
```

output:

```
   A   B  C
a  1  10  6
b  2  10  6
c  0   0  5
d  0  10  6
```